# Error returning custom object via GET method

Tags: rest, jackson, jersey-2.0

I am trying to run a simple example in Jersey which has a GET method and returns a Custom object. 
on calling GET I am getting following error

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain
```

I have looked into few answers on stackoverflow  where they are suggesting it to put a default constructor and jackson dependency in pom.xml.  I have already done that but no luck. Can some one please suggest what I am doing wrong.

Resource Class

```
@Path("customdatatyperesource")
public class CustomDataTypeResource {
    @GET
    public CustomResource1 get(@Context UriInfo ui) {
        return new CustomResource1();
    }
}
```

Custom Class

```
  @XmlRootElement
    public class CustomResource1 {
        @XmlElement
        String res;
        public CustomResource1() {  }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return "Custom : "+res;
        }
    }
```

pom.xml

[image: pom.xml]
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out that error is not in the code but in the request sent.

When I send the request with header `accept: text/plain`
I am getting the error MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/plain

The resolution is `accept` header needs to match with what resource can produce. 
In this case our resource is capable of producing XML or JSON

A better and more comprehensive way to write this code would be to put produce annotation on the methods.

`@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)`

and put correct `accept` header such as

`accept: application/json`